# Avoid special character escaping in Thymeleaf with Java

Tags: java, templates, encoding, thymeleaf

I am trying to use Thymelead as a template engine for some text templates that I have.

My template looks like this

```
free text 
[[${myVar}]]
more text
```

My Java code is

```
ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TEXT);

TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
Context context = new Context(ENGLISH, null);
context.setVariable("myVar", "My text with special characters such as ' < > &");
System.out.println(templateEngine.process("templateFileName", ctx));
```

I am expecting the above to print

```
free text 
My text with special characters such as ' < > &
more text
```

but instead it prints

```
free text 
My text with special characters such as &#39; &lt; &gt; &amp;
more text
```

Since I am working on plain text and not HTML or XML shouldn't it print the special characters unescaped ?

I have set mode to TEXT and encoding to UTF-8.

Please enlighten me.

Thanks

Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `[(${myVar})]` to print the text unescaped.

(I do agree that it's weird that `[[${...}]]` expressions escape HTML special characters in TEXT template mode.)

Answer (score 1):

Change your template from:

```
free text 
[[${myVar}]]
more text
```

...to:

```
free text 
[(${myVar})]
more text
```

As stated in [Thymealeaf's documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#expression-inlining):

> Expressions between `[[...]]` or `[(...)]` are considered **inlined expressions** in Thymeleaf, and inside them we can use any kind of expression that would also be valid in a `th:text` or `th:utext` attribute.
>
> Note that, while `[[...]]` corresponds to `th:text` (i.e. result will be HTML-escaped), `[(...)]` corresponds to `th:utext` and will not perform any HTML-escaping